# Errno::EPIPE (Broken pipe) and AWS::S3::ExceptionClassClash when trying to mix heroku, paperclip and S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip

I am trying to setup Amazon S3 with paperclip on heroku. I have everything working fine on my machine. I upload from my machine to S3 without any issues. I pushed my code to heroku and am seeing two issues:

```
AWS::S3::ExceptionClassClash (The exception class you tried to create (`AWS::S3::NoSuchBucket') exists and is not an exception)

2011-08-17T05:40:14+00:00 app[web.1]: Errno::EPIPE (Broken pipe)
```

I don't get why my local machine isn't having the same issues. Everything is exactly the same between the two (I pull from my git repo and push to heroku ... on my machine, everything is fine, on heroku it errors out).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the config like this: http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2009/4/7/config-vars/

Comment: thanks a lot for your help! solved our problem(s) perfectly. we owe you a coffee ;)

Answer (score 0):

Double check the region in which is created the bucket.

You can see it in the properties of the bucket: if it's different from US Standard proabably is not working for you.

Try creating a new bucket on US-standard and see if it works.